# HEXA to packed BCD conversion?

Tags: c, binary, bcd

How should I go about converting an uint8 array that contains hexa values into packed bcd values?
Would a simple shift by 4 positions do the work?
If possible I would appreciate a few examples in code to better understand my issue

Comment: What do you mean by "hexa values"? Is the array a string of hexadecimal digits? Of is just an array of arbitrary *binary* bytes? Also, for some specified input to your program, what should the expected output be? And what have you tried? Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And of course please  show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt.

Comment: In BCD, each _decimal_ digit is coded as a binary number of 4 bits. So you must first make sure that you have string of decimal digits, then convert each to a 4 bit BCD value.

Comment: Please be more specific - at the very least provide sample input and desired output for the given input.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude each element of the array can contain arbitrary binary bytes.
Also correct me if I'm wrong here but from what I understand BCD is , you take each digit of your number (for example 0x31 in hexadecimal ) and transform them in binary to get the BCD value(0x31  from hexa to BCD should be 0011 0001).Also I don't have an implementation in code as I think my aproach of shifting each element of the array by 4 to get packed bcd is flawed and I am looking for a starting point here.

Comment: It’s puzzling. If both nybbles of the byte are in the range 0..9 then the value is already BCD.  If you need to worry about signs (negative) then you need to know how the chosen BCD variant encodes them.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Also, in English, the abbreviation of hexadecimal is usually “hex”, not “hexa”.

Comment: As I stated above my array  has arbitrary binary bytes.That should include values from A to F.@JonathanLeffler

Answer (score 0):

The following code is an example of how to convert. It puts BCD digits in 4 bit nibbles, like `s="4660"` ==> `bcd[]= {0x46, 0x60}`

```
void toBCD(int x)
{
    int nchars, k;
    char s[20], *cp=s;
    unsigned char b, bcd[20], *p=bcd;

    nchars= sprintf(s,"%d",x);
    k=0;
    while (*cp) {
        b = (unsigned char)(*cp++ - '0');
        if (k==0) {
            *p= b;
            k= 1;
        }
        else {
            *p= (*p<<4) | b;    //shift left and put in right nibble
            p++;
            k= 0;
        }
    }
    if (k==1)
        *p= (*p<<4);
}
```

<sub>(the code does not return anything meaningful; it is just an example of the conversion)</sub>